# Why does increased variability of independent variables increase the correlation between them and the dependent variable

Tags: regression, distributions, correlation, intuition

Example Data:

```py
N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {   # https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html
        # numpy.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None)
        # scale is the standard deviation
        "x0": np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=6, N),
        "x1": np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=2, N),
    },
)
coef = np.array([2, 2])
df["y"] = df.dot(coef)
```

Correlation:

```
|    |        x0 |        x1 |        y |
|:---|----------:|----------:|---------:|
| x0 | 1         | 0.0350902 | 0.931288 |
| x1 | 0.0350902 | 1         | 0.396739 |
| y  | 0.931288  | 0.396739  | 1        |
```

Pair plot:

[image]

## Question

It's not obvious to me why `x0` is more highly correlated with `y` as a result of having an increased variance (the standard deviation of `x0` is 6, whereas that of `x1` is `2`).

So, my question is - why is this the case? Why does having a greater standard deviation in the distribution of an independent variable increase it's correlation with the dependent variable?

Comment: Suppose a fair coin is flipped 1000 times. $X_0$ is the number of heads in the first 990 flips, $X_1$ is the number of heads in the final 10 flips, and $Y = X_0 + X_1$ is the total number of heads. It shouldn't be surprising that $X_0$ affects the value of $Y$ much more than $X_1$ does.

Answer (score 1):

So $X_0, X_1$ are independent random variables, with
$$ X_0 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma=6), \\
   X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma=2) $$ Then we define $Y=2X_0+2X_1$.

Now think about this as two regression models, in model 0 $X_0$ is predictor for $Y$, in model 1 $X_1$ is predictor for $Y$. Then the "other $X$" becomes error term, for model 0 $X_1$ is error, for model 1 $X_0 $ is error term. Then it is clear that the error term is largest in model 1, and that is what is shown in your plots.

Alternatively (left as an exercise), use first the following formula for the covariance:
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
   \C(\sum_i a_i X_i, Z) = \sum_i a_i \C(X_i, Z)
$$ and then the definition of correlation.